# How to convert MSK time to SST time in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date, npm

I have an API which provides time as follows:

```
07:00 PM
```

The above time is in **MSK** (Moscow Standard Time) and i nesd to convert it in **SST** (Singapore Standard Time) using JavaScript or with any npm package

Comment: since it is just a time with no reference to date you can just add/subtract the difference in timezone?

Comment: How do i do that? Singapore time is 5 hours ahead of Moscow time

Comment: Russia last observed DST in 2010 with no plans to reintroduce it. Singapore hasn't observed DST since 1936 and likely never will (since it's just 1.3° off the equator), so as long as you're happy with considering the period after 2010, just add 5 hours to MSK and you're done (Singapore is +8, MSK is +3).

Comment: how do i add hours if i have datetime object in this format:    11/21/2022 19:00

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value from your API is a proper `Date` object, you can use the `setHours` method.

```
let example = new Date()
console.log(example.toTimeString()) // the before value
example.setHours(example.getHours() + 5) // add 5 to the current hours value
console.log(example.toTimeString()) // the after value
```

I don't think it will adjust the date, so if you add 5 hours to 2300hrs it may roll back to the beginning of the current day and not the beginning of the next. Your question only shows time, and if that is the only information you care about then this will not be an issue.